# How to register two class inherited from the same class using LuaBridge?

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I'm trying to register two class that inherit from the same class using LuaBridge, but failed.

How can I register three classes below?

```
    class A
    {
        public:
            int x;
    };
    class B1 : public A
    {
        public:
            int y;
    };
    class B2 : public A
    {
        public:
            int z;
    };
```

I can just register A and B1 like this

```
getGlobalNamespace(L)
    .beginClass<A>("A")
        .addConstructor()
    .endClass()
    .deriveClass<B1, A>("B1")
        .addConstructor<void(*)(void)>()
    .endClass()
```

And

```
getGlobalNamespace(L)
    .beginClass<A>("A")
        .addConstructor()
    .endClass()
    .deriveClass<B1, A>("B1")
        .addConstructor()
    .endClass()
    .deriveClass<B2, A>("B2")
        .addConstructor<void(*)(void)>()
    .endClass()
```

<s>is turn out to register B2 as if it inherits from B1.</s>

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry.....
I misunderstood the function "deriveClass".
I will answer my question tomorrow because of the limitation "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getGlobalNamespace(L)
    .beginClass<A>("A")
        .addConstructor()
    .endClass()
    .deriveClass<B1, A>("B1")
        .addConstructor()
    .endClass()
    .deriveClass<B2, A>("B2")
        .addConstructor<void(*)(void)>()
    .endClass()
```